# Get child and subchild of parent in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to generate some strings based on list data:

Given the following class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following List of related `Item` objects:

```
var list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Parent1", ParentId = 0 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Child1", ParentId = 1 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 3, Name = "Child2", ParentId = 1 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 4, Name = "GrandChild1", ParentId = 2 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 5, Name = "GrandChild2", ParentId = 2 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 6, Name = "GrandChild3", ParentId = 3 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 7, Name = "GrandChild4", ParentId = 3 });

list.Add(new Item { Id = 8, Name = "Parent2", ParentId = 0 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 9, Name = "Child1", ParentId = 8 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 10, Name = "Child2", ParentId = 8 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 11, Name = "GrandChild1", ParentId = 9 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 12, Name = "GrandChild2", ParentId = 9 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 13, Name = "GrandChild3", ParentId = 10 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 14, Name = "GrandChild4", ParentId = 10 });
```

Now I want to create strings like:

```
"Parent1:Child1:GrandChild1"
"Parent1:Child1:GrandChild2"
"Parent1:Child2:GrandChild3"
"Parent1:Child2:GrandChild4"

"Parent2:Child1:GrandChild1"
"Parent2:Child1:GrandChild2"
"Parent2:Child2:GrandChild3"
"Parent2:Child2:GrandChild4"
```

I have tried this:

```
private IList<Item> GetChild(int id, IList<Item> items)
{
    var childs = items
        .Where(x => x.ParentId == id || x.Id == id)
        .Union(items.Where(x => x.ParentId == id)
        .SelectMany(y => GetChild(y.Id, items)));

    return childs.ToList();
}
```

This code returns parent and all childs and sub childs but I can't make the desired strings from this.

So How can I do this using LINQ or foreach loop?

Comment: You are right, I should had added the tried code. I have updated my question. Can you answer now?

Comment: So you could either need to either 1) identify the leaves, and then collect a list of parents to the root of the tree and then join names with colons, or 2) turn this into a tree, i.e. wrap each item in a node structure that also contains the list of children for each node, and recurse through this tree maintaining the current colon-separated path and output it whenever you find a node with no children.

Comment: But both of those work with arbitrary depth trees and you could make some shortcuts if you know there are only ever two depths. e.g. build a dictionary of id -> item, then iterate the list and for each node look up its parent and its parent's parent items too, and if you have both then you have a grandchild and you have the two other items you'll need to make the string.

Comment: No, the depth can be n

Comment: You need a recursive method.  Linq byitself will not work.  I often in this case create a helper method that is called in side a Linq.

Comment: you are looking for a self join here probably

Comment: I agree with @Rup that a list doesn't seem like the ideal data structure here. You can certainly do what you're trying to do with a list, but it's not going to be as efficient. Is `list` being used in other ways elsewhere in your code that justify your choice of a list over a tree?

Answer (score 1):

With some joins you can get the expected output.

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T1fq6x)

```
public void WriteStrings() 
{
    List<Item> items = GetItems();
    IEnumerable<string> resultingStrings = from parent in items.Where(x => x.ParentId == 0)
          join child in items on parent.Id equals child.ParentId
          join grandChild in items on child.Id equals grandChild.ParentId
        select string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", parent.Name, child.Name, grandChild.Name);

    foreach(var item in resultingStrings)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output

```
Parent1:Child1:GrandChild1
Parent1:Child1:GrandChild2
Parent1:Child2:GrandChild3
Parent1:Child2:GrandChild4
Parent2:Child1:GrandChild1
Parent2:Child1:GrandChild2
Parent2:Child2:GrandChild3
Parent2:Child2:GrandChild4
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code with recursive method traverse list and print what's you want. Call Traverse method with list as a parameter.

```
public void Traverse(List<Item> list)
{
    var roots = list.Where(e => e.ParentId == 0).ToList();

    foreach (var item in roots)
    {
        Traverse(list, item);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

private void Traverse(List<Item> list, Item target, string str = "")
{
    str += target.Name;

    var children = list.Where(e => e.ParentId == target.Id).ToList();

    if (!children.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        return;
    }

    str += ":";

    foreach (var item in children)
    {
        Traverse(list, item, str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two approaches I mentioned in the comments. First identify leaves and then for each leaf work back up to the root building up the string:

```
// Build a dictionary of items
var itemsById = list.ToDictionary(i => i.Id);
// Build a dictionary of child items of each node; 0 = root
var childrenById = list.GroupBy(i => i.ParentId).ToDictionary(g => g.Key);

// Find leaf nodes
var leaves = list.Where(i => !childrenById.ContainsKey(i.Id));
// For each leaf, build up a list of parents up to the root then print
foreach (var leaf in leaves)
{
    var queue = new LinkedList<Item>();
    var cursor = leaf;
    do
    {
        // NB this will get stuck if there's a cycle in your tree.
        // You might want to guard against this!
        queue.AddFirst(cursor);
    }
    while (itemsById.TryGetValue(cursor.ParentId, out cursor));

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(":", queue.Select(i => i.Name)));
}
```

Alternatively, build a tree and recurse through:

```
// Build a dictionary of child items of each node; 0 = root
var childrenById = list.GroupBy(i => i.ParentId).ToDictionary(g => g.Key);

// Iterate through tree recursively
var path = new LinkedList<Item>();
var output = new List<String>();
Recurse(0, path, childrenById, output);
```

and

```
static void Recurse(int parentId, LinkedList<Item> path,
    Dictionary<int, IGrouping<int, Item>> childrenById, List<String> output)
{
    if (childrenById.ContainsKey(parentId))
    {
        foreach (var item in childrenById[parentId])
        {
            path.AddLast(item);
            Recurse(item.Id, path, childrenById, output);
            path.RemoveLast();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // This is a leaf node
        output.Add(String.Join(":", path.Select(i => i.Name)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            Item item = new Item();
            item.CreateList();
            Item.Recursive(0, new List<string>());

            foreach(string descendant in Item.descendants)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(descendant);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public static List<string> descendants = new List<string>();

        public static List<Item> items = null;

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }

        public void CreateList()
        {
            items = new List<Item>() {
               new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Parent1", ParentId = 0 },
               new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Child1", ParentId = 1 },
               new Item { Id = 3, Name = "Child2", ParentId = 1 },
               new Item { Id = 4, Name = "GrandChild1", ParentId = 2 },
               new Item { Id = 5, Name = "GrandChild2", ParentId = 2 },
               new Item { Id = 6, Name = "GrandChild3", ParentId = 3 },
               new Item { Id = 7, Name = "GrandChild4", ParentId = 3 },
               new Item { Id = 8, Name = "Parent2", ParentId = 0 },
               new Item { Id = 9, Name = "Child1", ParentId = 8 },
               new Item { Id = 10, Name = "Child2", ParentId = 8 },
               new Item { Id = 11, Name = "GrandChild1", ParentId = 9 },
               new Item { Id = 12, Name = "GrandChild2", ParentId = 9 },
               new Item { Id = 13, Name = "GrandChild3", ParentId = 10 },
               new Item { Id = 14, Name = "GrandChild4", ParentId = 10 }
            };
        }

        public static void Recursive(int parentId, List<string> ancestors)
        {
            List<Item> children = items.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId).ToList();

            if (children.Count  == 0)
            {
                descendants.Add(string.Join(":", ancestors));
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Item child in children)
                {
                    List<String> newAncestors = new List<string>(ancestors);
                    newAncestors.Add(child.Name);
                    Recursive(child.Id, newAncestors);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```